# BigQueryでカラム内のカンマで分割してフラグ作成する方法

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

【BigQuery】でのデータ加工についてご質問させてください。

カラム内にカンマ区切りで入っている、下記のようなデータがあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
SELECT
　"A" AS year , "1,2,5" AS product
  UNION ALL SELECT "A" AS year , "1,2,5" AS product
  UNION ALL SELECT "B" AS year , "3,9" AS product
  UNION ALL SELECT "C" AS year , "1,7,11" AS product
  UNION ALL SELECT "C" AS year , "1,7,11" AS product
  UNION ALL SELECT "D" AS year , "4,6,8" AS product
  UNION ALL SELECT "E" AS year , "2,4,10,11" AS product
  UNION ALL SELECT "E" AS year , "2,4,10,11" AS product
```

このデータに対し、カンマで文字列を分割して、下記のように、各文字列ごとのフラグを作成したいと考えているのですが、良い方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]